# What is causing this oblique border issue?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove oblique border issue, best to show it in a picture:

[image]

Here is the css applied to the div:

```
.blog_post {background: #fff}

.blog_post .post {
    border-right-color: #F1F1F1;
    border-top-color: #FF0000;
}
.blog_post .post, .blog_post .sidebar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.blog_post .post {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9A9570;
    border-color: #8F8960 #8F8960 -moz-use-text-color;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: -560px 0 0 -12px;
    padding: 28px 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 528px;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly.. that's what borders look like http://jsfiddle.net/Fqjv7/1/

Comment: Yes, I would like the borders to look like a square shaped, if possible.

Comment: If you removed the `border-right` it would make it square.. alternatively you could use `:before`/`:after` pseudo selectors to overlay something

Comment: You can't, because one would have to go on top of the other, and you have no way of defining that. So, you can either use the same colour (which doesn't work for your design, of course), so do something else, a container with a background image, an image on top or only one border (while the child has the other), etc.

Comment: I solved the issue for my specific case by removing border-top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easy way: Another container

You can't do this with traditional HTML borders as they work at shown above (that's how CSS triangles work!). The easiest way to get this effect is to wrap the element in another container.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PEGBK/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    border-top:10px solid red;
    border-bottom:10px solid red;
}

.inner-container {
    border-left:10px solid blue;
    border-right:10px solid blue;
}
```

### Hard way: `:before` and `:after`

This method is a little more tricky but you can manage to pull it off with only one wrapping element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NqV9x/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    border-top:10px solid red;
    border-bottom:10px solid red;
    position:relative;
    /* pad out the left and right to allow room for the border */
    padding:0 10px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:10px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:block;
    content:"";
}

.container:before {
    left:0;
}

.container:after {
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `inset box shadows`. They are pretty easy to use, and they don't require much CSS, nor do you have to change the HTML.

Check it out. [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWjFx/)

```
div {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 0px red;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    border-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after`

```
.border-fixed {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  border: solid 10px #DDD;
  border-top-color: #BBB;
  position: relative;
}

.border-fixed:before,
.border-fixed:after {
  content: "";
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #BBB;
}

.border-fixed:before {
  right: -10px;
  left: auto;
}
```